# How to Set ActiveX Control name and link on the install window of Internet Explorer?

Tags: c++, activex, atl

I created a ActiveX control using ATL, already package it with signature.
I want to use it on the webpage, but at the install window the name is `MyActiveX.cab` with no link. the `MyActiveX.cab` name can be changed by modifying the html page's  tag codebase attribute. but the name is still format like "XXX.cab" with no hyperlink.

I find a activex control from chinese website has its own name and link:
and its object tags are nothing different:

```
<object ID="CMBPB_OCX" 
CODEBASE="http://szdl.cmbchina.com/download/PB/pb50.cab#version=5,3,1,1" 
classid="clsid:F2EB8999-766E-4BF6-AAAD-188D398C0D0B" width="0" height="0">
</object>
```

---

[image: The pic]

---

[image: The pic]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC70749.gif))</sub>

---

the pic was taken from [MSDN Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/), it has link.

`Really want to know how to Set the activex control name?`

I try to get help from [How to Set ActiveX Control Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783209/how-to-set-activex-control-name), but still get stuck.

`I Signed the cab file and the activex dll file both`, and don't know how to put the name and hyperlink in that window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you sign **both** control and CAB file?

It looks like you didn't sign the **CAB** file. The installation dialog shows info from the CAB file signature. Or maybe signature is invalid...

Comment: I signed the cab already, the sign operation was done by a automatic web interface of my company.
In the cab file's property page, I can see the signature is valid.