# ActiveX Control Name is not available

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, activex

**ActiveX Info** - This ActiveX Control is

- Implemented using C#, VS 2008, .Net Framework 3.5
- Digitally Signed with valid Code Signing Certificate
- Installed using VS Deployment Project and Registered on Client Side

---

**Problem** - One of our web page loads this ActiveX Control, however for a first time visitor, the IE (I'm using IE9) prompts

`This webpage wants to run the following add-on: 'Control name is not available' from 'Not Available'`

After allowing it, then go into "Tool" => "Manage Add-ons", it's now there with proper Control Name & Publisher.

---

**Seeking** - I'm looking for solutions that will either

- Display correct information in the warning prompt, Control name & Publisher name, **OR**
- Remove the warning completely

---

**Researched Solutions** - I have found some suggested solutions, but none of them describe fully

- Display correct name by COM Shim approach on [MDSN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/66c90981-bd8c-493c-9270-a3f82232a41e)

  - Performance issue
  - Although I did go ahead downloading COM Shin Wizard, but lack of info after creating it
- Remove warning by setting up CLSID and domain as an approved domain in the registry during installation

  - Not sure which registry to create/update, need more specific registry values
- [How to Set ActiveX Control Name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1783209/381709) on StackOverflow

  - Bounty set by me, but maybe the question is too old which grabs no attention.
  - I'll start bounty on this question once the old one has expired.

---

*All helps are appreciated*

Comment: It sounds like your control's DLL isn't properly Authenticode-signed. Do you have a public URL that demonstrates this problem? Also keep in mind that writing ActiveX controls (or other IE extensibility) using .NET is not recommended for reliability and performance reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it solved by putting on to pre-approvaed list

> To put your control on the
> pre-approved list, you need to write
> the CLSID of the control to the
> following registry location.
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
>
> SOFTWARE
>
> Microsoft
>
> Windows
>
> CurrentVersion
>
> Ext
>
> PreApproved